# what is the best way to do redux in Haskell

Tags: reactjs, haskell, functional-programming, redux, ghci

I like. haskell and its type system and I find it interesting to write backend in haskell. however, IMO I don't think that switching to another language for the front end is good idea.

I want to share my code between the front end and back and use the validation and type and do not repeat myself.

looking for some architecture about front end I got to know to `flux` then `redux` and I liked redux the most.

what is the best way to write redux app in haskell. after some research I found `react-flux` but any other option that is more like redux

Comment: What do you mean by 'write redux app in haskell'? Do you mean writing a redux app front end in javascript with haskell backend? Or writing redux app front end in haskell and also with haskell backend?

Comment: the second, I want to use redux architecture in Haskell. am sold into using the same language for frontend and backend to share code re-use code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think the **best** way to do what you're calling *redux* here in Haskell is probably to use something that works with Conal Elliott's ideas.

These ideas are pretty strong, and probably one of the nicest implementation of some of them is in reflex-dom... here's the website for it: https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform

Word of warning, though: you *do* need to understand Haskell quite well to use it.

Comment: reflex looks promising and active on GitHub, however, could I know what makes you suggest `reflex` over other straight forward architecture - what Evan called it First order FRP- such as `react-hs` and `miso` [link](https://github.com/dmjio/miso) that are closer to Redux/Elm...

Comment: He asked for the **best** way to do this. The best way is continuous-time functions. Of course it depends on one's definition of best. I was choosing high-quality of result and efficiency over ease of learning for the average programmer. By "Evan" I assume you mean the creator of Elm. Elm is a primarily event driven system which abandons much of Conal Elliot's work. reflex-dom is **amazingly cool** in terms of what it's capable of.